# How to set parsing language to be Chinese when using TesseractOCR in Tika 1.13?

Tags: java, tesseract, apache-tika

```
TesseractOCRConfig config = new TesseractOCRConfig();
config.setLanguage("chi_sim");
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   language code

When I set language to be `eng` or `jpn`, the OCR process works all right, but I have to parse some pictures containing Chinese. `chi_sim` or `chi_tra` gives me "*Invalid language code*" exception and `chi` is not working. Can somebody help to fix it?

Comment: do you have the chi_sim package in your data folder? (traineddata i mean) PS. one more thing what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16.04, and have installed all needed packages including chi-sim.  The tesseract program is working well in the terminal. I have found the real cause of the exception lies in the TesseractOCRConfig class within tika-parsers 1.13 package, which has a if sentence to prevent wrong language code in the setLanguage method. After commenting this if sentence,  I can parse Chinese correctly in my code now. Thank you so much.